# how to get rid of white space around the custom bottom navBar flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-bottomnavigation

I created a custom bottom nave bar, but there is a white space still around it. How to get rid of it? also if I put a button inside a container in order to give it a height or width, the same issue will be found.

**The Image Is:**

[image]

**The Code Is:**

```
bottomNavigationBar: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
        // clipper: ,
        child: Container(
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.w),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: whiteColor,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: shadowColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: const Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: pageIndex,
            onTap: (int value) {
              pageIndex = value;
              setState(() {});
            },
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'home'.tr,
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.flag_sharp),
                label: "add_opportunity".tr,
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: 'profile'.tr,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Can you try removing the margin!

Comment: no change happens, if i do so @KrishBhanushali

Comment: try Scaffold: extendBody: true

Comment: make it as answer to accept it, @Jim

Comment: here you go, post an answer, good to hear it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try extendBody:

```
return Scaffold(
  extendBody: true,
  bottomNavigationBar: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
```